# Implement the addInPos method inside the LinkedList prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I need to implement the addInPos method inside the LinkedList prototype but I don't know what it is bad in my code...because the test no pass.
Implement the addInPos method inside the LinkedList prototype that must add an element in the indicated position. Both data will be provided as a parameter (pos, value). Where "pos" will be the position in which the "value" value should be added. In the event that the position in which the insertion is to be made is invalid, that is, it exceeds the size of the current list, it must return false.
If the node was added correctly return true.
Note: the zero position corresponds to the head of the LinkedList.

My code:

```
LinkedList.prototype.addInPos = function(pos, value) {

  if(pos > this.size) {
    return false;
  }
  const newNode = new Node(pos, value);
  let current = this.head;
  let previous;

  if(pos === 0) {
    newNode.next = current;
    current.prev = newNode;
    this.head = newNode;
  } else {
    for(let i = 0; i < pos; i++){
      previous = current;
      current = current.next;
    }
    newNode.next = current;
    newNode.prev = previous;
    current.prev = newNode;
    previous.next = newNode;
  }
 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With your structure ideally insertAt function would look like:

```
var insertAt = function(head, item, index) {
    var curr = head;
    var count = 0;
    while (curr !== null) {
        if (count === index) {
            var newNode = { data: item, next: curr.next, prev: curr };
            curr.next = newNode;
            break;
        }
        count++;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
};

insertAt(head, 2, 3);
```

Let me know if this works.
Also look at this LinkedList class I have created, insertAt function is currently missing, but from this stack question, I am planning to add it in my class as well.
[Class GitHub](https://github.com/dsinjs/linked-list)
[NPM package - @dsinjs/linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/linked-list)
[Complete documentation](https://dsinjs.github.io/linked-list/)

Comment: Hi Siddhesh Kulkami, thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: @Joha, how then come you don't mark this answer as accepted?